# Extjs4.1: Reproduce form Layouts

Tags: panel, extjs4.1, form-layout

Can anyone reproduce this type of layout in extjs4.1:

[image]

I try to reproduce this type of combination layout but for now i just do only a row or a column but not together at the same time

this is the code i use in extjs2:

```
[{
                    layout:'column',
                    border: false,
                    items:[{
                        width:220,
                        layout: 'form',
                        border: false,
                        items: [{
                            xtype:'textfield',
                            fieldLabel: 'asd',
                            name: 'clientId',
                            tabIndex: 1
                        },{
                            xtype:'textfield',
                            fieldLabel: 'lol',
                            name: 'clientId',
                            tabIndex: 11
                        }]
                    },{
                        width:220,
                        layout: 'form',
                        border: false,
                        items: [{
                            xtype:'textfield',
                            fieldLabel: 'qwerty',
                            name: 'description',
                            tabIndex: 2
                        },{
                            xtype:'textfield',
                            fieldLabel: 'kat',
                            name: 'description',
                            tabIndex:12
                        }
                        ]
                    },{
                        width:220,
                        layout: 'form',
                        border: false,
                        items: [
                        {
                            xtype:'textfield',
                            fieldLabel: 'duck',
                            name: 'description',
                            tabIndex: 3
                        }
                        ,
                        {
                            xtype:'textfield',
                            fieldLabel: 'lucky',
                            name: 'description',
                            tabIndex: 13
                        }]

                    }] 
                }]
```

Any type of help is usefull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [`HBox`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.HBox) layout, have alook at the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/kG95M/